# Code Flutter (lines kind of jump and look bad)

Tags: java, animation, processing, draw

So I have this little program (or sketch if you like). My problem is, and how should I word this, that the lines, when they are moving, kind of jitter and flutter a bit. Is this to do with the processing power of my computer, or should I code this in a different manner?

This is the code:

```
int i, j;

void setup() {
  size(1440, 900);
  background(0);
  smooth();
  strokeWeight(10);
  i = width/2 - (width/2);
  j = width;
}

void draw() {
  fill(0, 10); // semi-transparent black
  stroke(0);
  rect(0, 0, width, height); //legger seg lag på lag

  if (i < width-200) {
    i+=4;
    j-=4;
  }
  else {
    i = width/2 - (width/2);
    j = width;
  }

  stroke(255);
  line(width/2, height, i, 30);
  line(width/2, height, i+40, 30);
  line(width/2, height, i+80, 30);
  line(width/2, height, i+120, 30);
  line(width/2, height, i+160, 30);
  line(width/2, height, i+200, 30);
  line(width/2, height, j, 30);
  line(width/2, height, j-40, 30);
  line(width/2, height, j-80, 30);
  line(width/2, height, j-120, 30);
  line(width/2, height, j-160, 30);
  line(width/2, height, j-200, 30);
}
```

Comment: Without a runnable example, it will impossible to provide any kind of feed back.  What framework are you using? Swing, AWT, JavaFX....?

Comment: If your code is drawing the lines as fast as possible, you are getting redraw-interference from the screen. If your (unnamed!) graphics library provides it, use a dual-screen setup or a `vsync` like function. If it doesn't, add a `sleep(50)` (or its Java equivalent) after drawing for a 1/20 sec frame rate (but some flickering may still be visible).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that this is using the Processing framework.

Comment: If you want to reduce the frame rate, then `frameRate(int hz)` is the way to go. I'll note that I don't experience any jitter on my machine (Linux Mint 15, core i5, intel HD4000 graphics, processing 2.1, java 1.7.0_40).

Comment: I don't want to change the frameRate. What I want is for the program to run smoothly. So this is probably something to do with the computer I am on? I have an old mac (around 5 years old or something, intel core 2 duo 2.66 GHz with 4 Gb RAM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a quick profile with [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) it turns out that there are two culprits:

1. Rendering lines
2. Handling anti-aliased transparency

**Rending lines:**
Behind the scenes Processing is rendering each line as a shape([beginShape()](http://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html)/endShape()), in this case using LINES. You can give Processing a hand, and rather than using multiple beginShape/endShape calls(1 per line), just use one for all your lines:

```
beginShape(LINES);
  for(int k = 0; k < 200; k+= 40){
    vertex(hw, height);vertex(i+k, 30);
    vertex(hw, height);vertex(j-k, 30);
  }
  endShape();
```

**Anti-alias and transparency**
Using transparency is generally computationally expensive, especially for large images.
Running the snippet bellow, press the mouse button and see how frameRate changes when transparency isn't used.

Anti-aliasing is also computationally expensive. Not as much as transparency, but in addition too, it makes a difference. Press any key to toggle between aliased and anti-aliased graphics

```
Here are a few tweaks to your code:
int i, j;
int hw;
boolean smooth;
void setup() {
  size(1440, 900);
  background(0);

  strokeWeight(10);

  hw = width/2;
  i = width/2 - (width/2);//isn't this 0 ?
  j = width;
}

void draw() {
  fill(0,mousePressed ? 255 : 10); // semi-transparent black
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, width, height); //legger seg lag på lag
  if (i < width-200) {
    i+=4;
    j-=4;
  }
  else {
    i = 0;
    j = width;
  }

  stroke(255);
  beginShape(LINES);
  for(int k = 0; k < 200; k+= 40){
    vertex(hw, height);vertex(i+k, 30);
    vertex(hw, height);vertex(j-k, 30);
  }
  endShape();
  frame.setTitle((int)frameRate+" fps, smooth: " + smooth); 
}

void keyReleased(){
  smooth = !smooth;
  if(smooth) smooth();
  else       noSmooth();
}
```